# RubyTest in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby, rspec, sublimetext

I am trying to get [RubyTest](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) to work in Sublime Text 2. I followed the Instruction on the Github Readme and get the following error. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

```
/bin/sh: rspec: command not found
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To get this to work you only need to change one setting in the RubyTest package in sb2.

If you are using rvm, your rspec gem is installed through rvm and is not found in /bin/sh

So you need to set the RubyTest package for Sublime Text 2 to automatically check for your rvm environment variables.

What to change:

1) In Sublime Text 2, go to Preferences|Browse Packages. This will open up your packages directory.

2) Open the 'RubyTest' directory and look for the file 'RubyTest.sublime-settings'.

3) find the line that says:

```
"check_for_rvm": false,
```

and change it to:

```
"check_for_rvm": true,
```

save the change.

4) That's it. It should now work.

Good Luck

Comment: This works perfectly and it's easier than the rest of the answers.

Comment: If you can't find that directory/file and you have RubyTest installed, you can also get to the preferences file here by going to Preferences -> Package settings -> RubyTest -> Settings User and adding the `"check_for_rvm": true` to the existing hash or putting inside a new one if the file is empty.

Answer (score 43):

This worked for me:

If you're using RVM, open a project with command line from the project's folder:

```
subl .
```

Then, it'll hook the ruby version and gems.

Comment: Finally, I knew there had to be a simple solution!

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely due to using RVM. What is the output of

```
which rspec
```

on your command line?

Also of note, just because you've included rspec-rails in a Gemfile, does not mean that 'rspec' is an executable program that your system knows about.

You can edit the RubyTest.sublime.settings to refer to your particular path to the rspec executable and it should work.

Unfortunately, this has the nasty side effect of being tied to one particular version of Ruby. If you're using RVM to switch between versions, you'll have to update your sublime.settings.

One work around, is to run Sublime from the command line.

Comment: opening my project by running

    subl .

from the terminal is a good work-around for me!

Answer (score 6):

Running Sublime Text 2(2165) with RubyTest plugin. Ruby and Gems managed with rbenv (0.3.0).

First attempt to use RubyTest gave the following error:
    `/bin/sh: rspec: command not found`

From the command line I ran
    `which rspec`
and it returned no results.

After some digging, I read that `bundle install` does not put the executables in your $PATH.
[Alternative executable paths not picked up by shims sometimes](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/174)

In order to use the executible outside the app, I had to delete the gem installed by bundler and then install it manually.

`gem uninstall rspec`

`gem install rspec`

followed by

`rbenv rehash` (*Note* you will need to run `bundle` inside your app so it updates the location of the gem)

This had to be performed for each version of ruby I have under rbenv control.

Now when I run

`which rspec`

it is found in the path and RubyTest is able to grab it without any problems.

fwiw, I had to repeat the steps for cucumber as well.  To use all of RubyTests' features, ruby, cucumber and rspec executables need to be in your $PATH (for rbenv it is `~/.rbenv/shims/`).

Answer (score 4):

Try change the path to `usr/local/bin/`

I wrote a post on Sublime Text Build Scripts which should show you how to do this.

http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-build-scripts/

Comment: This doesn't really get rubytest running and loses the best part of rubytest which is the cmd-shift-e run last test command.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue for me. With rspec 1.3.2 what I just did to fix it is to edit the RubyTest.sublime.settings file in the plugin folder, changing the "ruby_rspec_exec" key from:

```
"ruby_rspec_exec": "rspec"
```

to

```
"ruby_rspec_exec": "spec"
```

It really depends on the location where you have your rspec executable file...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after installing RubyTest by cloning from the repo. I simply uninstalled and reinstalled the package inside Sublime using Package Control, then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a summary of this issue here: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/issues/36

Essentially, what Jim said was correct, you're running RVM or some other ruby vm manager that similarly monkeys with your PATH. Following the directions from this issue I did the following:

Install the binaries in my project

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

Add the path to my .bashrc and source it

```
echo 'export PATH="./bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Open the sublime project from the command line (so that PATH is available in Sublime Text 2)

```
subl .
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me (I encountered the same error as OP):

1. Install the RubyTest plugin through the package control manager. 
   Note* If you don't have the package manager installed - I highly recommend it for managing sublime plugins - more info [here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).
2. Be sure to add the [code here](http://RubyTest.sublime-settings) to your RubyTest.sublime-settings file.
   This file can be found at (from the menu): `Preferences -> Package settings -> RubyTest -> Settings User`
3. Save file, close Sublime and restart Sublime from the terminal in your project's folder using (so PATH is available in Sublime): `subl .`

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to change paths, run sublime from command line etc.
If you are using RVM, you only have to do this:

Go to Sublime Text 2, go to 
    preferances-> package settings -> RubyTests

and pick settings-user or settings-default (depending what you are using) and change line:

```
"run_rspec_command": "rspec {relative_path}"
```

to

```
"run_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path}"
```

And so forth - add **bundle exec** to all commands

[image]

Comment: I have found my own answer after some time, and now, after a year, it didn't work for me on a new machine :) the accepted answer helped http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504365/1612469 No wonder I got zero votes :)

Comment: this one worked for me while the accepted answer didn't. upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

I spent many hours struggling with this same problem! I could not get rspec to run within Sublime Text 2, using the Michael Hartl "Ruby on Rails Tutorial." It kept saying:

```
/bin/sh: rspec: command not found
```

I finally realized that the RubyTest package (https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) was looking in the WRONG PLACE for my RVM!

On my Mac, the path for RubyTest is `/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby Test`

First, to make RubyTest seek the RVM, I changed the parameter in RubyTest.sublime-settings from

```
"check_for_rvm": false, to "check_for_rvm": true,
```

Then I dug into the Python code of run_ruby_test.py: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/blob/master/run_ruby_test.py

At line 151, inside class BaseRubyTask, it had the wrong path for my RVM:

```
rvm_cmd = os.path.expanduser('~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby')
```

I changed it to the full correct path: `rvm_cmd = os.path.expanduser('/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby')`

If this is not your path, find the correct path by typing

`$ which rvm-auto-ruby` and substitute that instead.

After saving run_ruby_test.py, I went to Terminal, cd to my Rails application directory, and ran `spork`

Finally, I opened static_pages_spec.rb in Sublime Text 2. Now all the tests work from it!

Comment: I'm using RVM as well, but only had to set the `check_for_rvm` setting to `true` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rbenv and found that adding the following to my .bashrc did the trick

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/shims/rspec
```