# Rubytest issues with windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ruby-test

Just started messing with sublime text 2 / ruby and I can't get rubytest working for whatever reason. I used the following link to get started (http://railsinstaller.org/en).

Essentially none of the shortcuts work to activate anything and I followed all the instructions along with a few suggesting here.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was starting to work with Ruby, for me it was an easy fix I just had to add  ruby to my Windows PATH. Have you tried that?

Comment: I am really new at this so I am learning as I go. I will give your suggestion a try when I get home! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Okay sounds good and your welcome! Yeah I remember when I first started its kind of a pain to get it set up for the first time haha hopefully that fixes the problem for you!

Comment: I added the path to both bin folders for both ruby / rails in the windows environment variables and also checked versions at cmd line. Sublime text 2 still does nothing when I try the shortcuts.

Comment: Umm okay sounds good. Have you taken a look at this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513142/rubytest-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1)

Comment: I tried almost everything there and I dont get any feedback until I go the bundle route. When I enable bundle I get errors when trying to use the shortcuts to run anything.

Comment: File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_  
File ".\run_ruby_test.py", line 372, in run
  File ".\run_ruby_test.py", line 366, in load_last_run
  File ".\run_ruby_test.py", line 145, in load_config
  File ".\run_ruby_test.py", line 167, in bundler_support
  File ".\run_ruby_test.py", line 237, in find_project_root
AttributeError: 'AnonymousFile' object has no attribute 'partition_folder'